# Calculate prop.test() p-value and effect size pairs in aggregated dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, p-value

After running an experiment, I gathered data and reshaped in this format:

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~element, ~sessions, ~begin, ~complete,
         "baseline",       256,     67,        15,
        "variation",       580,    167,        22
        )
```

Than I aggregated as:

```
df %>%
  group_by(element) %>%
  mutate(sessions_to_begin = round(begin/sessions*100,2),
         sessions_to_complete = round(complete/sessions*100,2)) -> df_agg


df_agg <- tibble::tribble(
     ~element, ~sessions, ~begin, ~complete, ~sessions_to_begin, ~sessions_to_complete,
   "baseline",       256,     67,        15,              26.17,                  5.86,
  "variation",       580,    167,        22,              28.79,                  3.79
  )
```

I want to achieve create a df that contains a proportion test p-value for the pairs baseline/variation for the metrics `session_to_begin` and `sessions_to_complete`.

It would look like:

```
df_test <- tibble::tribble(
                           ~metric, ~baseline, ~variation, ~p-value, ~effect_size,
                "session_to_begin",      25.9,       29.5,      "-",          "-",
             "session_to_complete",      6.03,       3.95,      "-",          "-"
             )
```

I assume that for the effect size this could be a viable option:

https://rdrr.io/cran/pwr/man/ES.h.html

Comment: I get what you're asking, but it would still help if your example were fully reproducible from a blank R session. That means you need to include the libraries you are using (sure looks like `tidyverse`, or at a minimum `dplyr`, are in use here). Also, it might be useful to know how you arrived at the `df_agg` numbers after starting with `df`.

Comment: thanks for the comment! edited my question: @mmyoung77